# Javascript idle visitor checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a Javascript library (preferably a jQuery plugin) or simple mechanism to check if a visitor is idle?  For example, if the visitor to a webpage has been there more than 5 minutes only moving their mouse but not clicking any buttons or pressing any keys, then call a particular Javascript function.

It seems like I could just call `setTimeout()` for my desired idle time and then call `clearTimeout()` upon any mouse click or keyboard press by having something like `$('body').click(clearTimeout(`....  But I'm sure there are issues I don't want to have to figure out.  The one thing I definitely don't want to have happen is for my site to think someone's been idle and they haven't really been.  The other way around is ok.

Comment: What if your page is in some tab in the background? I'm not idle when I'm on other web pages.

Comment: Good question, that would count as idle for my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, very possible and there are a couple sites that use this (like banks and Mint) with great success. Take a look at these two blog posts:

[http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/creating-a-mint-com-style-idle-logout-timer-using-jquery/](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/)
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/

I have used this approach in the past with Admin pages within websites to a fair amount of success, especially after adding the modal dialog box informing users that the session was about to expire. This helps the user to feel like the web application/site is working with them to help.

Comment: the idleTimer jQuery plugin the blog entries reference is exactly what I was looking for (though not the script the blog entries are about).  Thanks.

Comment: When I used it I did modify it a bit, but the blog posts serve as a good primer to what had to be done. Glad this was helpful.